# python Error: import module not found after making executable

Tags: python, executable

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk7xZ.png)

```
from pathlib import Path
import linecache
import pyperclip
print('Looking for a path...')
print('Found path!')
Path('C:/Users/Akush/Documents/Warcraft III/CustomMapData/YouTD/')
a = linecache.getline('savecode.txt',7)
pyperclip.copy(a)
print('{} copied to clipboard!'.format(a))
```

So everything works fine in pycharm, but when i made .exe from .py it gives "Module not found" error in CMD

Do you know what i did wrong here?
thanks for help!

Comment: Can you add the code used to make the exe and to run it afterwards?

Comment: What are you using to convert the python script to an executable? What commands are you using to convert the script?

Comment: i used cmd to convert py to .exe by pyinstaller --onefile scriptname.py

Comment: It works just fine for me. When you run pyinstaller you need to be in the root of your project directory. It will then create a folder called 'dist', where you will find your executable file.

However, I have noticed some issues with your code. The variable dir is never used, what is your intention with that variable. You also print out Looking for a path and found path, but you don't have any code in between the two that actually looks for a path.

Comment: Ye i found the file in the dist, but after running the code it gives me error in CMD Module not found, i will provide a jpg in a while. edit: Image added

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are your packages installed globally or inside of a virtual environment? I was able to successfully run your code in Pycharm with the packages installed in a virtual environment. I also pip installed pyinstaller in the virtual environment and ran it in the same virtual environment.

Comment: @Kickin_Wing I am using Pycharm and installed module pyperclip using Pycharm, the dir var was used previously but is not needed now, just need to delete it.

Comment: Can you try running pip install pyinstaller and then pytinstaller yourprogram.py, from the terminal at the bottom of pycharm?

Comment: i did and still won't work

Comment: There is a build directory that is created when running pyinstaller, you will find a file called warn-test.txt. Can you include the contents of that file?

Comment: Your error states that pyperclip is not found. Try running pip install pyperclip in the terminal at the bottom of pycharm

Comment: https://easyupload.io/qrvt77 here is warn-test.txt

Comment: What are you using as your python interpreter for this project? You can check this in settings -> project -> python interpreter. Are you using the system interpreter or virtualenv

Comment: i think its venv

Comment: Okay i had wrong interpreter chosen and now it works, thanks for help!

Comment: Glad to help! I cleaned up your code a little bit below as well. Let me know it that works for you and mark as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using pycharm, make sure you are using the correct python interpreter in the project settings. If you are using the system interpreter, the modules won't be found in a virtual environment

I cleaned up your code a little:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import linecache
import pyperclip

# Specify the path
dir = Path('C:/Users/Akush/Documents/Warcraft III/CustomMapData/YouTD/')
# Specify the file
file = 'savecode.txt'

# Start Searching for Path
print('Looking for a path...')

# Check if Path exists
if dir.is_dir():
    # Set the currect working directory to the found path
    os.chdir(dir)
    # Let the user know the path has been found
    print('Found path!')
    # Check to see if the file exists
    if Path(file).is_file():
        # Get lines from file
        a = linecache.getline(file, 7)
        if a == '':
            print('Nothing found in file')
        else:
            # Copy line to clipboard
            pyperclip.copy(a)
            print(f'{a} copied to clipboard!')
    else:
        print("File not found")
else:
    print('This directory does not exist')
```

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you

Comment: Accepted! i'm glad u helped me and if you could edit "import os" as it's not visable it